# Should force be added force to Rigidbody in the Start, Update or FixedUpate function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm new to Unity.

I have `Rigidbody2D` and I want to add constant `velocity` to my player. 
I want to know whats are differences or advantages/disadvantages or bast practice in applying velocity to `Rigidbody2D` in `Start` or `Update` (or `FixedUpate`)

When I apply velocity on start everything works fine, so why we add velocity every frame ( `Update` method )  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to add **constant** velocity to my player.

The [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) function is eliminated in this case since it's called once only when the script is GameObject and script enabled. If you need to apply force over and over again then the [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) function is not something you should use.

The [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) function is used to do anything every frame. For example, manually moving object every frame.

The [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) function is used to do something to `Rigidbody` and this includes adding force to it every fixed frame. This is what you need to use since you're doing something to a `Rigidbody` object.

The other one you didn't mention is the [`LateUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html) function. This is used when you want to make a GameObject follow a camera since it's calld after all `Update` functions have been called.

---

Unity also has a [`ConstantForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ConstantForce.html) utility to simplifies adding constant force to `Rigidbody`. With it, you can add force once to `ConstantForce` in the `Start` function and it will handle the rest until you change the force.

```
ConstantForce2D cForce = targetObj.GetComponent<ConstantForce2D>();
cForce.force = new Vector2(0, 100);
```

Comment: but when I add velocity ( not addForce) on Start method everything works fine, my player is moving as it should and then I make script for camera following. So Start metod work fine I guess because velocity shouldn&#39;t need to add every frame its like speed and not is constant variable .

Comment: You're not adding a velocity. You are setting velocity which sets a new force without accounting the current force. It's **not** a constant force. *It will eventually stop*. The reason you think so is because you're adding a large force to the rigidbody. If you add a tiny force to it, you will see that it will start slowing down ASAP due to drag and gravity. If you want a constant force, use the `ConstantForce`  component like I mentioned and do in the `Start` function or do it manually with `AddForce` in the `FixedUpdate` function.